# Substitute "for loop" in my function to make code faster on Big data?

Tags: r, performance, time, time-series

I have made a following function in R that will find out the number of obs in a certain time interval.

```
time_interval <- function(time_vector){

  time_seq <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
                  to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 23:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")


  time_seq <- strftime(time_seq, format="%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
  start_time <- times(time_seq) 
  end_time <- times(start_time) + times("01:59:59")
  time_df <- data.frame(start_time = start_time, end_time = end_time)


  format_time_vector <-times(time_vector)  #converting into times format 


  time_count <- c() 
  time_interval <- c()

  for(i in 1:NROW(time_df)){
    time_count <- append(time_count,sum(format_time_vector >= times(time_df[i,1]) & format_time_vector <= times(time_df[i,2])))

    time_interval <- append(time_interval,paste(as.character(time_df[i,1]), as.character(time_df[i,2])))

  }
  my_new_data <- data.frame(timeinterval = time_interval, timecount = time_count)

  return(my_new_data)
}
```

I have following data frame

```
structure(list(email_address_hash = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26", 
"00198ee5364d73796e0e352f1d2576f8e8fa99db", "35c0ef2c2a804b44564fd4278a01ed25afd887f8"
), class = "factor"), open_times = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("04:39:24 10:39:43", 
"09:57:20 19:00:09", "21:12:04 07:05:23 06:31:24"), class = "factor"), 
    desired_training_list = list(list("04:39:24"), list(c("21:12:04", 
    "07:05:23")), list("09:57:20")), desired_testing_list = c("10:39:43", 
    "06:31:24", "19:00:09")), .Names = c("email_address_hash", 
"open_times", "desired_training_list", "desired_testing_list"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is how is my data looks like 
[image]

**Aim :- Find out the time-interval in which we have maximum observation. We are taking a time interval of 2-hours. For example if we have 10 obs in between time interval 00:00:00-2:00:00 and 5 obs in between time interval 8:00:00-10:00:00. We will select 00:00:00-2:00:00 as an output and displayed it in the column of dataframe**

Please note if we have same obs in all time-interval then we can randomly pick any time-interval for the best time interval of that customer.

I tried following approach

```
data$training_best_time <- rep('NA',NROW(data))
data$training_best_time_count <- rep(0,NROW(data))
data$training_best_time<-  apply(data[,3,drop= FALSE], MARGIN = 1, function(x) as.character(setorder(time_interval(as.vector(unlist(x))), -timecount)[1,1]))

data$training_best_time_count <- apply(data[,3,drop= FALSE], MARGIN = 1, function(x) as.character(setorder(time_interval(as.vector(unlist(x))), -timecount)[1,2]))
```

This is how is my output looks like 
[image]

**Problem:-** When I run this function over millions of rows this will take 4-5 hours to complete or even much more. I want to make it faster

**Problem Area Estimate :-** From my experience with data.table I think it is my self made function that is making R to spend this much time. Although I am not sure. I also tried for loop inside data.table but this is not much helpful in bringing down the execution time.

Please help me to speed up my code. Please let me know if you have any difficulty in understanding my problem

Comment: Why downvote ? If you don't help then simply leave

Comment: You big problem is that you are using `append`. Don't. Instead, pre-allocate the vectors and fill them in. For example, `time_count <- numeric(nrow(time_df))` above the loop, then `time_count[i] <- ...` inside the loop. It is NOT the `for` loop that is the problem. (not my downvote, but this issue has been discussed a number of times heara and elsewhere.)

Comment: thank you. But are you that this will decrease the time to many folds ?

Comment: It will reduce / eliminate needless copying and re-copying of your growing vector(s), which you are implementing with `append`. The rate of this slowdown increases as the number of iterations increase.

Comment: A better way to tackle these things is to have a row for each open time, duplicating the email hash column. Then you can easily transform the times into a proper time format, `cut` them into time intervals of two hours, and aggregate to find the time interval with the highest count using data.table.

Comment: @mpjdem would that work with overlapping times? The `start_time` values are in one hour sequence, with the `end_time` values 2 hours after, so there's an overlap, meaning some rows need to be counted in more than one group.

Comment: @mpjdem can you please explain a bit more. I am confused with your approach

Comment: The downvotes are likely because this is a code review question and hence actually outside the scope of stackoverflow. For the rest, @lmo is right: append() is your main problem, not the for-loop. Your attempt to use apply() doesn't help a thing, as apply() is a loop as well.

Comment: Please learn to work with longitudinal data structures as @mpjdem is suggesting. The data format you are working with is not good for manipulation. Looking at your other questions on stack overflow related to this data, it seems you are making extremely complicated loops, because the basis of your code (the data) is in a bad format.

Comment: @Wietze314 can you please give me an example to whatever you are referring . I am not getting his point

Answer (score 1):

Just to stay inside your function (and not mention how it's called), you might find some improvement by adjusting the `for` loop slightly. You can preallocate the vector to begin with, which should help, and also remove the `time_interval` part of the loop entirely (since you can vectorize that part pretty easily):

```
time_count <- vector( mode = "integer", length = nrow( time_df ) )
for(i in 1:nrow(time_df)){
    time_count[i] <- sum(format_time_vector >= times(time_df[i,1]) & format_time_vector <= times(time_df[i,2]))
}
time_interval <- paste( time_df$start_time, time_df$end_time )
```

Also, I just realised you're running the entire script twice, once for each column of your output, you can run it once instead, taking both outputs as list items, then binding them as your data frame afterwards.

```
data2 <- lapply(data[[3]], function(x) as.character(setorder(time_interval(as.vector(unlist(x))), -timecount)[1,]))
data2 <- do.call( rbind, data2 )
names( data2 ) <- c( "training_best_time", "training_best_time_count" )
data <- cbind( data, data2 )
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Let me check this code and see how much time it will decrease. I have pasted the example of how I used my function. can you see that ?Please let me know if you are unable to find it

Comment: You're welcome. I just added another section, which should almost halve your computation time.

Comment: Once again thank a lot. Even I didn't find this. Just wondering is there anything else that we can do to speed up this code ?

Comment: Probably, sure. I think you might be expecting too much from an answer on SO though.